# Pandas replacing values of duplicated ID with values of the first occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":['1','4','2','3','4','3','4'],"Color":['Green','Org','Yellow','B','Orange','Blue','Orange']})
```

what I am trying to do is to replace the value in the col ['Color'] for the records with a duplicated ['ID']. The ['Color'] value has to be replaced with ['Color'] value in the first occurrence of the ['ID'].
So that the above dataframe will result in the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":['1','4','2','3','4','3','4'],"Color":['Green','Org','Yellow','B','Org','B','Org']})
```

As you can see, for istance, 'Orange' has been replaced with 'Org' since this one was the ['Color'] value at the first occurrence of ['ID']= '4'

The original datset is (8M,140) so I can't drop the duplicates as I will lose important data. I struggle to find a logic that basically links duplicated() and replace(). I have searched the internet but all I can find are solution to replace duplicates with NaN or the same value for all. If I missed the post where this problem has been addressed please direct me to it.

Thank you in advance for you time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` to extract the first occurrences and then `map`:

```
s = ~df.ID.duplicated()
df['Color'] = df.ID.map(df[s].set_index('ID')['Color'])
```

Output:

```
  ID   Color
0  1   Green
1  4     Org
2  2  Yellow
3  3       B
4  4     Org
5  3       B
6  4     Org
```